# Where can I find the documentation (or source) of the `nix` command line tool?

Tags: nix

`nix` was introduced in [release 2.0](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-relnotes-2.0) "*to eventually replace all `nix-*` commands with a more consistent and better designed user interface.*" There are no man pages yet, and the `--help` flag is somewhat terse without any examples:

```
$ nix --help
Usage: nix <COMMAND> <FLAGS>... <ARGS>...                                                     
...
Note: this program is EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change.
```

Or

```
$ nix repl --help
Usage: nix repl <FLAGS>... <FILES>...

Summary: start an interactive environment for evaluating Nix expressions.

Flags:
      --arg <NAME> <EXPR>       argument to be passed to Nix functions
      --argstr <NAME> <STRING>  string-valued argument to be passed to Nix functions
  -I, --include <PATH>          add a path to the list of locations used to look up <...> file names

Note: this program is EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change.
```

There is a warning at the bottom of the help sections that "*this program is EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change*", but `nix` command examples are already showing up (albeit scattered all around) in the Nix manuals. See [5.3. Modularity](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-modularity) in the NixOS manual, for example:

```
$ nix repl '<nixpkgs/nixos>'

nix-repl> config.networking.hostName
"mandark"

nix-repl> map (x: x.hostName) config.services.httpd.virtualHosts
[ "example.org" "example.gov" ]
```

It would be helpful to find the source or dev docs at least.

Answer (score 0):

The [source for the `nix-*` commands](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/tree/2.2.2/src), and the [source for `nix`](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/tree/2.2.2/src/nix) in the [NixOS/nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/tree/2.2.2) Github repo. (All repo links are pinned to the latest 2.2.2 release.)

My best guess is that all docs, other than source comments, are in [release notes in the Nix manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-relnotes), starting from [release 2.0](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-relnotes-2.0).

Comment: Please update this answer if you have more info, or if there is a better one, I'll just delete this one. Thanks